# Can I safely overvolt DC-brushed motor when using a driver?

Tags: dc-motor, brushed-dc-motor, motordriver

I'm trying to use a car jump-starter to power my robot and for some reason its voltage is not 12 V but in the range of 15-16 V.

I have step-downs for logic and servos, but my main motors are connected to the battery directly through the drivers (BTS7960 and L298N). Motors are rated 12 V and 20 A (stall)/2 A (load) and will be used to move the robot, so I think that the motors will not work longer than a 5 min at a time. I'm afraid of frying the motors, so my questions is:

How can I use the battery I have to power up my motors and avoid additional step-down converters (because currents are too big)?

Will the motor drivers protect my motors from overcurrent if I reduce my max. speed (PWM) by 10% so the motors will operate using the safe(ish) current?

Is it possible to somehow easily limit the current to let the motors work with 15-16 V instead of 12 V? I can see inrush current limiters but I suspect they wouldn't help here.

The only thing I know about electronics at the moment is Ohm's law and I'm not always sure how to apply it so I'm trying to use prefab components where possible.

Comment: PWM reduction sounds plausible but it would be helpful to see the schematic of the two driver circuits and how the current limit is implemented.

Comment: If the "motor drivers" are actually PWM speed controllers, then that should probably work as long as the motor driver can accept 16 V input voltage.

Comment: @Jens I am not sure what exactly you're asking for. Should I add the link to BTS7960 and L298N datasheets? Or you mean I should post my wiring scheme, if yes I don't think it would be helpful because it is dead simple, battery and motors connected directly to drivers as well as µC logic.

Comment: @VladimirTagakov I can't speak for Jens, but I am not sure what "the motor drivers" are. Are you using motor drivers? If so, I think you should add the manufacturer and part number to your original question and also add a link if you have one to any technical documentation for them. If the "driver" sits between the power supply (charger) and motor, it may serve to limit voltage to the motor. So it is of interest.

Comment: So I assume there are no extra current limiters in the circuit, just short circuit protection in BTS7960 and exploding L298, ok. If you reduce the PWM, you reduce the effective voltage of the motor. So you can limit this to 12V using 75% PWM at 16 V supply. The driver chips are rated much higher. Why do so many people use this extreme inefficient, old, even idle hot L298?

Comment: Of course you have a FUSE there? You don't need condensing metal damp on your eyes.